# Flask-SQLAlchemy: there are no foreign keys linking these tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy with the following `models.py`:

```
class DomainRoot(db.Model):
    # Int/Float fields
    id      = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # String fields
    domain  = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    # DateTime fields
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    # ForeignKey relationships
    domain_paths = db.relationship('DomainPath', backref='domain_root', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DomainRoot %r>' % (self.domain)

class DomainPath(db.Model):
    # Int/Float fields
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # String fields
    domain_path = db.Column(db.String(256), index=True, unique=True)

    # DateTime fields
    created     = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    updated     = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    # ForeignKey fields
    domainroot_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('domainroot.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DomainPath %r>' % (self.domain_path)
```

When I try to query the DomainRoot object, I get an error:

```
InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship DomainRoot.domain_paths - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

As far as I can tell, I have added the proper foreign key fields.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy autogenerates the table name `domain_root`, with an underscore.  You refer to `domainroot` without the underscore.

In general it's easier to define the fk and relationship in the same model, and avoid using string references.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class DomainRoot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class DomainPath(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    root_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(DomainRoot.id))
    root = db.relationship(DomainRoot, backref='paths')

db.create_all()
db.session.add(DomainRoot(paths=[DomainPath(), DomainPath()]))
db.session.commit()
print(DomainRoot.query.get(1).paths)
```

```
[<__main__.DomainPath object at 0x7fc27f443f28>, <__main__.DomainPath object at 0x7fc27f443fd0>]
```